# How can i reduce the complexity of this code(given below)?

Tags: c, algorithm

**Problem statement:**
 Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below N.

**Input Format:**
First line contains T that denotes the number of test cases. This is followed by T lines, each containing an integer,N.

**Constraints :**

1 <= T <= 10^5

1 <= N <= 10^9

**Output Format:**
For each test case, print an integer that denotes the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below N.

This is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    long t,i,x;
    scanf("%ld",&t);
    long y[t];
    for(i=0; i<t; i++) {
        scanf("%ld",&x);
        long j,k,sum= 0;
        if(x<=3)
            sum= 0;
        else if(x<=5)
            sum= 3;
        else {
            for(j=3; j<x; j+=3)
                sum= sum + j;
            for(j=5; j<x; j+=5)
                if(j%3!=0)
                  sum = sum + j;
        }   
        y[i] = sum;
    }   
    for(i=0; i<t; i++) {
        printf("%ld\n",y[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It was too slow. It timed out, so it got terminated.

Comment: Since this is an algorithmic problem and your problem is unlikely to have anything to do with implementation details (at least for now), a good idea might be to provide your attempted solution as pseudocode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a solution with a time complexity of O(T):

Use the formula for sum of integers `1+2+3+...+n = n*(n+1)/2`.

Also note that `3+6+9+...+(3*n) = 3*(1+2+3+...+n) = 3*n*(n+1)/2`.

Figure out how many numbers divisible by 3 there are. Calculate their sum.

Figure out how many numbers divisible by 5 there are. Calculate their sum.

Figure out how many numbers divisible by 15 (=3*5) there are. Calculate their sum.

Total sum is `sum3 + sum5 - sum15`. The numbers divisible by both 3 and 5 (hence by 15) are both in sum3 and in sum5, so unless we subtract sum15 they would be counted twice.

Note that the sum will overflow a 32 bit integer, so make sure you use a 64 bit integer type.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve constant complexity if you employ the Ancient Power of Mathematics.

First figure out how many numbers divisible by three there are.
Compute their sum.
(You do not need any loops for this, you only need elementary arithmetic.)

Repeat for five and fifteen.

The total is a simple expression involving those three sums.

The details left as an exercise for the reader.